# One header for various variables

Tags: c++, header, constants

I have a large program, which I am using for modelling a physical system. Consequently, I need to define different constants and macros. For this reason I have chosen to have one header-file, in which I define all of these things. I include this header-file in all the .cpp-files in my project, where needed. Below is an example of such a header file (constants.h):

```
 #ifndef CONSTANTS_H
 #define CONSTANTS_H


 //global library
 #include <fstream>

 //constant
 const double PI = 3.1415926535;

 //macro
 #define exp_2(x) ((x)*(x))

 #endif
```

The library fstream I include here, because many of my .cpp-files require it. I'm not a professional programmer, but I would like to hear what the general opinion is of making a large simulation based on this principle. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Using that macro can lead to unexpected results, e.g. `exp_2(f())` will call `f` twice. Use a function instead.

Comment: The constant is fine, the macro is not. Use an inline function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of the macros. They look like functions but the semantics is different, because of the double evaluation of (x) in your example, which may have performance consequences or broken logic. For example, with macro max/min/abs:

Ex. 1:

```
// would spill extra innocent blood 
val = max(100, GetBloodSample(BS_LDL))
```

Ex 2:

```
// can unexpectedly return a number which is less than 3.     
val = max(3, schroedingerCat.GetNumPaws())
```

(When defined as `#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))`)

Use inline functions instead. Also, you should be using Tau [instead of PI](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto)))

Comment: Is it preferable to write the inline function in constants.h or in a .cpp files?

Comment: @niles_1710373: If you write an `inline` function in a .cpp file, it is usable ONLY in that single .cpp file. That's why you generally put them in header files, who can then be included in each .cpp file.

Answer (score -3):

At the very least you should define your const variables as *static* to avoid errors and compiler warnings on (possible) multiple inclusions:

```
static const double PI = 3.1415926535;
```

Another approach would be define PI in a single *.cpp* file and then *extern* it in the header.

Comment: As already said in response to an earlier (deleted) answer, `const` variables at namespace scope have internal linkage by default. In any case, putting the definition in a `.cpp` file would prevent the compiler using the value at compile time, which could have huge performance impact in a simulation that uses PI heavily.